# Getting key of each object inside array of objects into an array: Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an object with the following format

```
var obj = [{
  "a": 1
}, {
  "b": 2
}, {
  "c": 3
}];
```

Would want to fetch only keys out of each object inside this array of objects into a new array

Something like this:
`["a","b","c"]`

Have tried the following but it is not working :

```js
var obj = [{
  "a": 1
}, {
  "b": 2
}, {
  "c": 3
}];
let result = obj.map (({ val }) => val)
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Merge to a single object by spreading into `Object.assign()`, and then get the keys:

```js
var obj = [{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":3}];

const result = Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...obj));
console.log(result);
```

Or use `Array.flatMap()` with `Object.keys()`:

```js
var obj = [{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":3}];

const result = obj.flatMap(Object.keys);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Liking the second the best

Comment: There may be a slight difference between the 2 options if the objects have similar keys: the `Object.assign` method will return unique keys while the `flatMap` method will return all the keys per object regardless of any duplicates.

Comment: Yep. You'll need to use a Set to get unique keys if you prefer the 2nd option.

Answer (score 2):

I'd `.map` and extract the first item in the `Object.keys` of the object being iterated over:

```js
var obj = [{
  "a": 1
}, {
  "b": 2
}, {
  "c": 3
}];

const result = obj.map(inner => Object.keys(inner)[0]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Doesn't work if an object in the array has multiple keys

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `Object.assign` and `spread(...)` operator to solve this issue

```js
var mainObj = [{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":3},{"23":1},{"32b":2},{"232c":3}];

const allKeys = Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...mainObj));
console.log(allKeys);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [.map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) to open the array and then use Object.keys to return the key from the object.
Please refer the example I have made.I hope it helps

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G66AEBM9ZJCD

```
let object1 = [{a:1,b:2,c:3}]
        let final = object1.map(function(object){ 
            return Object.keys(object)
        });
```