# Javascript how do i dynamically find keys in my array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, find, key

I'm trying to find all the keys that are in my array to figure out if some keys already exist in there. Tho when I try to put in the keys seperate like this:

```
console.log(this.UrlArray.find(({color_ids}) => color_ids));
```

It works, but if I try doing it with the variable with the actual keys in it:

```
console.log(this.UrlArray.find(({prefixEqual}) => prefixEqual));
```

It doesn't work. The values that belong to the keys aren't important, but I stil can't figure out how to do it.

Array example:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
  0:
    bd_shoe_size_ids: Array(2)
      0: "6601"
      1: "6598"
    length: 2
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
    [[Prototype]]: Object
  1:
    color_ids: Array(2)
      0: "6056"
      1: "6044"
    length: 2
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
    [[Prototype]]: Object
  2:
    manufacturer_ids: Array(2)
      0: "5875"
      1: "5866"
    length: 2
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
    [[Prototype]]: Object
  length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

I asked something like this before, but I got linkes to answers that had nothing to do with what I'm trying to do and it closed.

As desired outputs I just wanna see bd_shoe_size_ids, color_ids and manufacturer_ids when I console log it.

Comment: could you provide an example of your desired output

Comment: @SaeedShamloo I Added an explanation of what I want to see

Comment: `data.map(o => Object.keys(o)[0])` solves your problem?

Comment: @Saeed Shamloo ... certainly not ... using `Object.keys(o)[0]`is ill advised for the index of a key within a keys array could change due to several reasons and the OP would not know why all of a sudden the code starts breaking.

Comment: Both answers work great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = [
    { bd_shoe_size_ids: [1, 2] },
    { color_ids: [3, 4] },
    { manufacturer_ids: [5, 6] },
];

const output = data.map(Object.keys).flat();

console.log(output);
```

Comment: The downvote after the first error prone approach has been edited and changed to the current solution is undeserved for this straightforward script does exactly what was ask for ... retrieving a list of keys from all of the array object's property names. (One of cause still could do ... `const output = [...new Set(data.map(Object.keys).flat())];` in order to assure an array of unique keys.

Comment: @PeterSeliger, actually I just found that it is a duplicated question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/57109438/14032355

Comment: Thanks man! I had a friend who had the same problem. Works perfect

Comment: @thijs, check the duplicated question commented above. there is a better solution.

Comment: @ikhvjs Yeah thanks man those work to